# The NumPy module was reloaded (imported a second time). This can in some cases result in small but subtle issues and is discouraged

Tags: python

How to solve it? What should I do?

It is on pyhotnanywhere by the way. It just don't work. I tried to load it ( Import & pip install) it does not work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I found a problem. But this happened:

aiogram.utils.exceptions.NetworkError: Aiohttp client throws an error: ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [Network is unreachable]